# how to query mongoDb with array of boolean fields?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My mongoose model schema looks like -

```
{
 email: { type: String},
 Date: {type: Date},
 isOnboarded: {type: Boolean},
 isVip: {type: Boolean},
 isAdult: {type: Boolean}
}
```

In my frontend I have 3 checkboxes for "isVip", "isOnboarded" and "isAdult" options. If they are checked I'm adding them to an array, which I'll pass to the server. Let's say if "isVip" and "isAdult" are checked, I will pass [isVip, isAdult] in post api to server. Now how can I write a query to get all the documents with the fields in array as true i.e in above example how can I retrieve all docs with {isVip: true, isAdult:true}

I'm having trouble because the array values keep changing, it can be only one field or 3 fields. I couldn't find a way to give condition inside mongoose query.

```
 User.find(
 { [req.query.array]: true},
 { projection: { _id: 0 } }
)
```

User is my mongoose model.
I want something like this (documents with the value 'true' for the fields given in the array) and 'req.query.array' is the array with field names I passed from frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create your object in JS and pass then to mongo in this way:

```js
var query = {}
if(isVip) query["isVip"] = true;
if(isOnboarded) query["isOnboarded"] = true;
if(isAdult) query["isAdult"] = true;
```

And then you can use the mongoose method you want, for example:

```js
var found = await model.find(query)
```

And this will return the document that matches the elements.

Also, note that this is to create and object to be read by the query, so you can use this into an aggregation pipeline or whatever you vant

Check the output:

```js
var query = {}
query["isVip"] = true;
query["isOnboarded"] = true;
query["isAdult"] = true;
console.log(query)
```

Is the same object that is used to do the query [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L27TVj2keMn)

```json
{
  "isVip": true,
  "isOnboarded": true,
  "isAdult": true
}
```

Also, to know if your post contains "isVip", "isOnboarded" or "isAdult" is a javascript question, not a mongo one, but you can use something like this (I assume you pass a string array):

```js
var apiArray = ["isVip","isAdult"]
var isVip = apiArray.includes("isVip")
var isAdult = apiArray.includes("isAdult")
var isOnboarded = apiArray.includes("isOnboarded")
console.log("isVip: "+isVip)
console.log("isAdult: "+isAdult)
console.log("isOnboarded: "+isOnboarded)
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by aggregation pipeline but I'm assuming it doesn't concern me in this scenario? Also I was looking at your SO profile to get your social so that I can send you this question. I will try that object method and get back to you.

Comment: Yes, it fits. If yo use `User.find(query,{ projection: { _id: 0 } })` is exactly what you want (I think). I've named "aggregation" as append, to say this JS object can be used in more scenarios, but it works for your task.

Comment: I'm new to mongoose, so I thought there's some sort of syntax/concept in mongo for this scenario that I don't know. Anway it works. Thank you. I hope there's someway to tag you in my future questions.